# wp_redirect () doesn't work in nginx?

Tags: redirect, wp-redirect

I made a simple redirection plugin that works like this:

```
add_action('wp_head', 'myredir');
function myredir(){
    if ( is_404() ) {
        $Path=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
        wp_redirect( 'http://old.example.com'.$Path );
        exit();
    }
}
```

The goal is redirect 404 errors to the old domain (I need to do a manual migration from an old website and it's going to take ages)

On Apache it works fine, on Nginx it doesn't work. What can I do to fix my plugin? The [Redirection](https://it.wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/) plugin works fine and it looks like is using wp_redirect, so there something wrong with my code

Comment: This is not related to nginx at all. The latest hook on the front end for HTTP headers is `template_include`.

Comment: using hook for template_include worked perfectly. So this is a change in Wordpress 4.7 and not because of nginx? Because I have another install on apache+wordpress 4.6.1 where my code works fine

Comment: No, this isn't new. `wp_head` was always too late as Mark pointed out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should not have worked on apache as well. `wp_head` is too late to make a redirect as there is already some output sent at that point and php will not send the http headers required for the redirection. You need to hook on `wp_loaded` or any other hook before output actually happens.

Comment: I hooked on get_header and it worked fine

Comment: +1, it is just such an esoteric hook, I decided not to mention it, maybe I should had.